# Pinch Zoom on iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, ios-simulator, zooming

I have never gotten this to work. What the heck am I doing wrong? :) I have a scroll view, the minimumZoomScale = 0.85, the maximumZoomScale is 2.0. I add a subview to the scroll view. The size of the subview is larger than the scrollview and I've set the scrollview's content size equal to the size of the subview.

Subview is 850 x 1100, scrollView is 722 x 935.

```
scrollView.contentSize = subview.frame.size;  
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.85; 
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
```

How do I pinch zoom in the simulator? I've read online that I'm supposed to hold down the Option key while click-dragging, but that never works for me. I've tried all of the other modifier keys and none of them work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you hold down the option key, do you see 2 gray circles in the sim?

Comment: Nope. The grey circles do not appear (even after implementing the fix from Anomie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you remember to set a delegate for the scroll view and return the appropriate view from `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`? Otherwise, post some actual code.

Comment: Nope, I totally missed that in the documentation. It's properly pinch-zooming now. However, I'm still not seeing the 2 grey dots that are supposed to show up when I hold down the Option key. :/

Comment: Same. I don't see the two grey dots